# JSP file and button value

Tags: java, rest, jsp

I have a **JSP** file. Inside that file I want to take the value when the button is pressed.

```
<button value="Honduras" type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
```

I am trying to extract `value="Honduras"` when button with `name="add"` is pressed.

```
String productName = request.getParameter("add"); //Expected productName="Honduras"
```

But I get the following error which refers to the line above:

```
Message An exception occurred processing [/index.jsp] at line [68]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP line:

```
<button 
   value="Honduras" 
   type="submit" 
   name="add" 
   class="btn btn-primary">
      Add to Cart
</a>
```

Uses a `button` to open the tag, but uses a `a` to close the tag

Not sure if this is the issue, but it is incorrect